# Cannot add foreign key constraint laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5

I have this migration:

For article

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

For category

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I try to run the command `php artisan migrate` I get an error:

```
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table`articles` add constraint articles_category_id_foreign foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Several times checked everything I can not find the problem.

Comment: You `categories` table migration, must run before the `articles` migration for that to work. Because the articles migration references the `category` table when creating the foreign key. Are you sure that's the order in which the migrations are run? (if you're not sure, check the timestamps that are part of the migration filename).

Comment: @bogdan, Yes, categories migration run of the last! How do I change the order?

Comment: The migration filename is formatted like this `yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss_name.php`, so it begins with the timestamp when the migration was generated. Just make sure the migrations timestamps are in the order you want them to be executed.

Comment: @Bogdan, Thank you very much, I will succeed!

Comment: @Bogdan, Now, when I run the command `php artisan migrate:rollback` i get an error: `[ErrorException] include(laravel/database/migrations/2015_05_31_165814_create_categories_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: That means that the `categories` migration was registered in the `migrations` table. Make sure the entries there match the renamed filenames.